Veblen's proof of Jordan's Theorem for Polygons
I as studying Veblen's proof of Jordan theorem for polygons. At the end of the proof he claims: "it is evident that $C'D'$ does not meet the boundary of the simple polygon $p_n$"....Why this should be so evident? And where do we use the fact that the polygon is simple?
These are the two lemmas he uses:


Thanks for any answer and help!

Look at the edge $e = P_1P_2$, and consider all segments $e_{i}$ joining a vertex $P_i$ to the neighboring vertex $P_{i+1 \bmod n}$. (I think that's what Veblen is talking about when he says "line joining two vertices" --- they're supposed to be sequential vertices of the polygon. We know (because $P_n$ is simple!) that $e$ does not intersect any of the $e_i$ except at the endpoints of $e$. The union of the $e_i$ (leaving out $e = e_1$) is a closed set, so its complement is open. Let $P$ be the midpoint of $e$; that's in the complement, so there's a closed ball $B$ of some radius $r > 0$ around $P$ that meets none of $e_2, e_3, \ldots, e_n$.
Now simply let $C' = PC \cap \partial B, D' = PD \cap \partial D$, and we see that the segment $C'D'$ meets none of the edges $e_2 ... e_n$. It also misses the edge $e = e_1$ because both $C$ and $D$ are in the same halfplane defined by the line containing $e$, hence so are $C'$ and $D'$.
This argument is a bit more concrete than Veblen's -- I pick a particular point $P$ rather than an arbitrary one, etc., --- and uses some point-set topology that Veblen ignores. But I think it's the gist of what Veblen was trying to say.

Okk, thanks for your clarification. If, as you say, these "lines joining two vertices of $p_n$" are the edges of the polygon, do you think there is a way to find those points $C'$ and $D'$ by using only the axiom of incidence and order? For example, we can consider all the intersections of these lines (the lines containing the edges of the polygon) with $PC$ and $PD$, and then taking $C'$ as the one of these points which is closest to $P$ (and similarly for $D'$), but then we would have to show that $C'D'$ does not intersect the boundary of the polygon in any point.

I don't know the axioms of incidence and order, so I can't help here. But this is a theorem about the cartesian plane, right? So using the usual topology seems like a reasonable thing to do. Sorry not to be able to help further.

It is the Jordan curve Theorem for polygons. The image I sent is taken from Veblen's "A system of axioms for Geometry": he puts this theorem as a result of the axioms of incidence and order (as Hilbert does too in his "Grundlagen der Geometrie"). Don't worry, thanks for your interest !
